# Add "code" button to wordpress tinyMCE

Tags: wordpress, button, tinymce

I've been following this tutorial, and many like it: http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons

```
function myplugin_addbuttons() {
   // Don't bother doing this stuff if the current user lacks permissions
   if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') )
     return;

   // Add only in Rich Editor mode
   if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
     add_filter('mce_buttons', 'register_myplugin_button');
   }
}

//Should add 'code' to the tinyMce buttons on the rich editor.
function register_myplugin_button($buttons) {
   array_push($buttons, "code");
   return $buttons;
}


// init process for button control
add_action('init', 'myplugin_addbuttons');
```

All I want to do is add the "code" button to the rich text editor. It's already in the HTML editor side. From the way the tutorial mentions it, it seems as though I could just write in array_push "code" into buttons. But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how the WordPress integration of TinyMCE works, but do you have access to the configuration used in TinyMCE for the toolbar buttons?

Comment: unfortunately wordpress recently did away with the tinymce config file. So, no. It actually turns out that my code worked. But that in tinymce, "code" doesn't mean <code>, it generates a button for the html editor popup. What the..

Comment: So Kristian, you weren't looking for the button to bring up the HTML Source view in TinyMCE but rather something else?

Comment: yes. I wanted to make use of the actual <code> tag </code>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to add settings to the TinyMCE config (which I'm not sure you do based on your previous comments) then you could add the following.

`style_formats : [{title : 'Code', inline : 'code'}]`

What this will do is add a "*code*" item in the Style drop down that will wrap the selected text in the code tags.

If you can't get to the config to add this, then you may need to develop a TinyMCE plugin that registers that format programmatically. BTW, the link to how to develop a TinyMCE plugin on the WordPress article you reference is no longer right. Check out the [How-to article](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin) instead.

Finally, if all else fails, you could develop a plugin that wraps the selected text ([ed.selection.getContent()](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.dom.Selection.getContent)) in the code and returns it using [ed.selection.setContent()](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.dom.Selection.setContent)

Answer (score 3):

I've written a plugin that does exactly that, i.e. it provides a button named 'codeElement' which users can use to wrap text in a code element or tag.

- [TinyMCE Plugin page on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3535796&group_id=103281&atid=738747)
- [direct download](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/download.php?group_id=103281&atid=738747&file_id=446337&aid=3535796)

Comment: Links need updating - both are broken.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled over the http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-code-element/ WordPress plugin, which does the job.