# TinyMCE Sanitizing input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce-4

I'm trying to use [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) (version 4.1.2) as a WYSIWYG editor. Logged in users can write their own pages and see directly what will be shown on the page when a visitor visits.

Now, I'd like for the html to be stored directly. For example:

The logged in user sees `This is my text!`, but in fact TinyMCE displays it as `<p>This is my text!</p>`. There's also certain styles like a `<h1>` and links that can be added.

Now, a user can insert a hyperlink, giving the link and text that should be displayed. Problem is however, if a user manually write `<a href='example.com'>Example</a>`, it shows in the editor like so but gets stored in pure html as well, so when displaying it will just be a hyperlink with the text `Example`.

This is how my code sort of looks like (left out configuration):

```
tinymce.init({
    setup: function(editor){
        editor.on('change', function(e){
            $('[name="'+editor.id+'"]').next("textarea").html(editor.getContent({format: 'html'}));
        });
    }
});
```

So the text from the TinyMCE field gets copied into a `<textarea>` that is inside a `<form>` which gets submitted when saving.

Something like this:

[image: TinyMCE input of user]

gets stored as:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p><a href="example.com">example</a></p>
<p><a href="example.com">test</a></p>
```

Which leaves me no way to distinguish genuine links and pure text, so I can't process it after the storing of the data.

I've already fiddled around with the `editor.getContent({format: 'html'})` format options, like `format: 'raw'`, but with no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully i'm understanding your question correctly.

It looks like you're wanting to display whatever your user inputs EXACTLY as they input it without actually processing whatever HTML the user wrote in as HTML. Am I correct? 
I believe this addresses the issue you're having:

https://kokoblog.net/php/fix-tinymce-auto-convert-html-code-to-element-tag

However, if you're only concerned about how it looks where it's stored, and not how it looks when it's processes then you'll want to add code blocks to tinyMCE and make sure your users understand that they need to select the code option whenever they're going to write raw HTML.

```
    style_formats : [{title : 'Code', inline : 'code'}]
```

src: [Add "code" button to wordpress tinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153599/add-code-button-to-wordpress-tinymce)

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really what I'm looking for. The code that is styled in the editor is actually eg `<h1>Title</h1>`, which is good. However, when a user manually writes `<h1>Title</h1>`, I want to display it raw like that. So only the things a user writes should be processed with sometihng like `htmlspecialchars()`, to prevent accidental closing of extra tags and to allow only tags the editor supports.

Comment: Okay, yeah that was my thought... In that case you'll need to enable a code tag format and have your users use that. Since the only thing that TinyMCE does is wrap your text in HTML it doesn't have any way to detect whether it's re-wrapping pre-formatted HTML. This is the same as most other similar editors, there are actually few that force html code to be displayed, rather than parsed.

Comment: I suppose another option would be to write a javascript extension which would look for html tags as you're writting, and if a tag is found auto-wrap it in a [code]...[/code] segment.

Comment: Hmm I thought since it was called a WYSIWYG editor it would indeed be WYSIWYG... I another option would be to use BBCodes, so all the formatted text is eg `[h1]Title[/h1]`. In this case I could use `htmlspecialchars()` and a BBCode parser to properly diplay eveything

Comment: Nevermind, I guess this will result in the same issues but with the BBCode's instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe most WYSIWYG editors have the same limitation. Wordpress does the same thing, and the only reason that stackoverflow's doesn't is because it's been modified to recognize tags and leave them alone. I'd be interested to hear about one that acted differently nativley though. So maybe someone else will reply with a suggestion :) Or let us know if you find a way to accomplish your needs!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same problem you had.
I did some testing and it appears that when a user types the HTML tags it sends them with HTML entities vs when a user clicks the bold button it sends them as their actual character (at least when encoding is set to XML).
I then used this on the backside to filter out user-written ones and display them like normal text.
If that doesn't work you can use `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({ format: 'text' })` to get the text without the formatting then you could do some back-end code to determine which tags are user made based on which tags aren't in the raw text

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).